# Send email via AWS Lambda where body is UTF8

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

I can't figure out how to get my email browser (I'm using mail.yahoo.com at the moment) to decode UTF-8 data sent via my AWS Lambda function. The email is sent and received fine, but the UTF-8 data shows up in quoted-printable format.

The headers should be:

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

... but as you can see, I can only specify UTF-8 via "Charset," from the AWS JavaScript SDK, which isn't working.

```
    // create email params
    var params = {
        Destination: {
            CcAddresses: [],
            ToAddresses: ['dummy@email.co']
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: message
                },
                Text: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: message
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                Data: 'New email from ' + domain_name
            }
        },
        Source: 'aws@' + domain_name,
        ReplyToAddresses: ['dummy@email.co']
    };
```

So the problem is the browser doesn't appear to be receiving the proper content-type headers, which I believe is a function of some variable I'm missing.

Comment: I may have found my answer but I'd like someone to clarify for me - I may only be able to accomplish what I want using the granularity afforded to me by the ses.sendRawEmail function.

Comment: I don't readily see where the problem would arise using sendEmail.  Can you show the headers from the incorrect mail?  Also, why are you sending both `Html` and `Text` with the same value `message`?  That isn't right.  If your body is really HTML, remove the entire `Text: { ... }` section, or change to `Text: { Data: 'Your device cannot render this message in its original format.' }`. You are creating multipart/alternative where you probably should not be.